# how to use grep -f and -v together

Tags: grep

I have 2 files and I extracted information from file 2 based on file 1 by using `grep -f file1 file2`.
Now if I want to use the output file to check if the columns based on file 1 are not there how can I do this efficiently. Grep -f -v do not work together.
I tried the `comm -12 file1 file2` command but it does not work.
Need some guidance on `grep -F -x -v -f file1 file2`

Kindly help.

Comment: Read `man grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Your command works as expected:

```
$ cat file1
b
c
$ cat file2
a
b
c
d
$ grep -Fxvf file1 file2
a
d
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I was wondering if I could have as output only those fields from file2 which are present in file1, the rest ignored. Kindly help.